# What is causing the wispy white artifacts in this photo?

Tags: artifacts, iphone

I took this photo at a wedding using an iPhone 7 Plus, and I noticed these wispy white lines most noticeably around the trees and clouds. All the other photos from the same vantage point and time did not have these wisps. What is the cause of these artifacts so can I avoid them in the future?

[image]

Comment: Why the dv? Is this SE only for experienced photographers? I'm a total amateur with little experience whose only camera is an iPhone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably there is grease on the front lens element, I would try removing it and see if this solves the issue